# Validar datos comparando con un array que tiene los datos válidos

Tags: php, array

Tengo un array de este tipo:

```
$array = array("rojo","azul","verde","amarillo", ...);
```

Y luego in input donde el usuario debería introducir un valor que esté dentro del array.

¿Cuál sería la mejor forma de **comparar un dato con un array** para ver si hay coincidencia con uno de sus elementos?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como te mencionaron en el comentario hay una función en php (https://www.php.net/in_array) para verificar valores adentro de un arreglo.
No hay mucha ciencia, serías así.

```
<?php
$valor_input = "rojo";
$array = array("rojo","azul","verde","amarillo");

if(in_array($valor_input, $array)){
   // Si esta
}else{
   // No esta
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

prueba con esta función:

```
 function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false)
{
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

llamada a la función:
=====================
if ( in_array_r($dato_buscado,$array) )
{
       print "ENCONTRADO!!!\n";
}
```